# ng-grid with "controller as" syntax

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

[This GitHub issue](https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/issues/1040) says no, but can [ng-grid](http://angular-ui.github.io/ng-grid/) be used when following Angular's "controller as" syntax?

**Update:**

Here is the basic example as seen on the [ng-grid site](http://angular-ui.github.io/ng-grid/):

http://plnkr.co/edit/lBgeAf?p=preview

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngGrid']);
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.myData = [{name: "Moroni", age: 50},
                     {name: "Tiancum", age: 43},
                     {name: "Jacob", age: 27},
                     {name: "Nephi", age: 29},
                     {name: "Enos", age: 34}];
    $scope.gridOptions = { data: 'myData' };
});
```

Here is my attempt at "controler as" syntax using the the basic example:

http://plnkr.co/edit/fI00U1?p=preview

```
(function() {

  angular.module('myApp', ['ngGrid']);
  angular.module('myApp').controller('MyCtrl', MyCtrl);

  function MyCtrl() {
    var vm = this;
    vm.myData = [{name: "Moroni", age: 50},
                     {name: "Tiancum", age: 43},
                     {name: "Jacob", age: 27},
                     {name: "Nephi", age: 29},
                     {name: "Enos", age: 34}];
    vm.gridOptions = { data: "myData" };
  }

})();
```

Comment: What would prevent you from using the "controller as"? Have you tried it and there is an error?

Comment: Hello, meanwhile ng-grid has been renamed to UI-Grid and is in major version 3. Is this still an unanswered question and if yes can we agree on version 3.x.x?

Answer (score 4):

Actually, the `controller as` syntax is just a shorthand for assign the controller instance into its own `$scope`, so the `MyCtrl as mc` would be equivalent to something like this:

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope['mc'] = this;
}
```

Therefore, you could just change the `gridOptions` to this:

```
vm.gridOptions = { data: "mc.myData" };
```

**Example plunker:** http://plnkr.co/edit/S4wyfB?p=preview

BTW, to prevent a confusion, you should use the same variable name to refer to the controller instance, I mean `vm` and `mc`.

Comment: The `vm` isn't meant to be used outside of the controller definition. As recommended on John Papa's [AngularJS Style Guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angularjs-styleguide#controllers) _controllerAs with vm: Use a capture variable for this when using the controllerAs syntax. Choose a consistent variable name such as vm, which stands for ViewModel._ Although your suggestion seems to work, using the view's controller instance name `mc` inside the controller's definition seems wrong.

Comment: Also, in your example, why does `vm.gridOptions` output as undefined on the page?

Comment: Actually, my suggestion is the opposite. The `vm` should be used instead of `mc` in html. And that just to be consistent as suggested in John Papa's guide since both are refer to the same thing: controller instance. One accessible in html, while other in controller, so why don't use the same name? And that will solve the `undefined` as well, you have to use `mc.gridOptions` in html currently.

Comment: I don't think that's quite right, because it tightly couples the alias used in the "controler as" of the view to the controller implementation. But, it does work as a workaround. Anyway, I just tried changing all of the references to `vm` and it was still showing `undefined`.

Comment: ouch! ...I tried to switch the plunkr to use ng-grid 2.0.12 and 2.0.13 and THAT doesn't seem to work... :( sad_panda

Answer (score 1):

Although a bit late, I found a workaround to this issue which requires an assignment to the data array for both `$scope.myData` and `vm.myData`, like so:

```
$scope.myData = vm.myData = [{name: "Moroni", age: 50}, ...];
```

As the array is a composite data type, this means that the property on scope stores a reference to the object. Thus, you can still use the `controller as` syntax in your controller to manipulate the data and be sure that the $scope.myData will be updated as well.

Here is a fork of your [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Bikli3?p=preview) which shows that it works.

**Note:** In ngGrid v.3.0 (which is not released yet), `controller as` syntax works normally and doesn't require any hacks.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use vm as shown below

```
vm.gridOptions = { data: "vm.myData" };
```